How did Scuttle learn about the wedding before Grimsby
Having a small child, I've seen Disney's 1989 The Little Mermaid often enough that I've started to wonder about certain plot glitches.
Towards the end of the movie, it's clear that Eric has developed feelings towards the mute Ariel; in the morning, she's in her guest room in the castle when Scuttle the seagull arrives, with this news:

SCUTTLE: Ariel! Ariel, wake up! Wake up! I just heard the news.
Congratulations, kiddo, we did it!
SEBASTIAN: What is this idiot babbling about?
SCUTTLE: Right - as if you two didn't know, uh? The whole town's
buzzin' about the prince gettin' himself hitched this afternoon! You
know, he's getting married!

Ariel rushes down the stairs to see Grimsby, the Prince's chief servant, Eric and Vanessa (the disguised Ursula) speaking

GRIMSBY: Well, uh - err, Eric. I-it appears that I was mistaken. This
mystery maiden of yours does - in fact exist. And - and she is lovely.
(holding Vanessa's hand) Congratulations, my dear.
ERIC: We wish to be married as soon as possible.
GRIMSBY: Oh, yes - of course, Eric, but, er - but these things do take
time, you know...
ERIC: This afternoon, Grimsby. The wedding ship departs at sunset.
GRIMSBY: Oh, oh - very well, Eric - as you wish.

How are everyone in town talking about a wedding, when Eric is just now raising the subject with the person who can make it happen?  Or is everyone in town speculating about Eric marrying Ariel (whom he has been seen with in public several times)?
